LDAP Integration for Laravel Project
I am currently having a trouble when authenticating a default, non-modified AD user in my Laravel Project. I am using this extension called LdapRecord-Laravel
Before making this post I made sure that I have established a connection between my Laravel Project and my Active Directory Server.
php artisan ldap:test

The problem is: Basically the main problem here is that, I have to edit first the mail of the AD user in the Attribute Editor and insert the email/mail of the newly created AD user that I have created(eg. johndoe@example.com) before I can log in that AD user.
So the sequence should look like this:
Create User(johndoe@example.com) in the Active Directory Users and Computer under the Users > Right Click the user, properties and navigate to Attribute Editor and find the mail and insert johndoe@example.com
What I want to achieve: Are there any way on to not manually input the email and log in as is after creating the AD user?
Here is my Laravel Code for this one:
LoginController.php

 public function ldapAuth(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = [
            'mail' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        ];

        // Attempt LDAP authentication
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);
        } else {
            // Log the failed attempt for debugging purposes
            Log::error('LDAP authentication failed', $credentials);

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Invalid credentials or user not found.',
            ]);
        }
    }

dasboard.blade.php
<div class="w-full max-w-md">
        <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 py-6">
            <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-center mb-4">Dashboard</h2>
            @auth
               <h1> {{ Auth::user()->getName( )}}</h1>
            @endauth
            @guest
                <p>Hello Guest </p>
            @endguest
        </div>
    </div>

and lastly my config/auth.php
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User::class,
            'rules' => [],
        ],
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

